# OOP structure of Pytorch

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

I have started learning OOP for implementing my DL models in Pytorch. Where can I find the OOP structure of Pytorch. By structure I mean the class structures (i.e. inheritance structure of classes like Sequential container). I know Module class is base for most structures.

Also I was exploring Pytorch on github and I am confused how import statements in Pytorch works. For example, the Module class is defined in `torch/nn/modules/module.py` but we only import `torch.nn` and write `nn.Module` to represent the Module class. Should it not be `nn.modules.module.Module` by the way it is stored on github?

```
# Example of using Sequential
model = nn.Sequential(
nn.Conv2d(1,20,5),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv2d(20,64,5),
nn.ReLU()
)
```

Sequential class in defined in `/torch/nn/modules/container.py` file but we just use nn.Sequential here?
Also I didn't find `__call__` method in Sequential class then how the above code calling the class as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python what you import inside a file becomes part of the file. So when you import  `nn.modules.module.Module` in `__init__.py`(which is inside nn folder), it becomes part of the nn module.

Here I will give a quick example.

Let's see we have three files `file1.py`, `file2.py` and `file3.py`, and we have a variable `var = 10` defined in `file1.py`.  If we have imported this variable inside `file2.py`, `file3.py` can directly import the variable from `file2.py`.

file1.py

```py
var = 10
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import var
```

file3.py

```
from file2 import var
print(var)
# Prints 10
```

Now let's go back to your question. As you said the `Module` class is defined inside `nn.modules.module.Module`. But this class has been [imported first inside `nn/modules/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0b8931fe4bdeb5c204fc831f0135868fd02b4efe/torch/nn/modules/__init__.py#L1) and then it [was imported inside  `nn/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0b8931fe4bdeb5c204fc831f0135868fd02b4efe/torch/nn/__init__.py#L1). That is why you can import Module class from nn package.

But importing will not change the type of objects you will create from the class.

```py
from torch.nn import Module

module = Module()

print(type(module)) # torch.nn.modules.module.Module
```

Comment: What about calling Sequential class as a function ?

Comment: If your class implements ```__call__``` method, then the objects created from that class will be callable. This means you can call the objects the same way you would call a function and that will invoke a ```__call__``` method of the object.